# Anyway to restore AFP as the default in 10.10?

Tags: macos, smb, afp

In OS X 10.10, Apple moved from AFP to SMB3 as the default method of connecting to servers (Command + K). Anyone know a way to restore this back to AFP?

Answer (score 1):

You can still connect to AFP servers, you just need to make sure to include the `afp://` at the beginning of the server name/IP. Unfortunately, I have not found a way to restore the default to AFP.